# Which report do we use for Google Analytics custom triggered events?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm created a method that will send a custom event to Google Analytics and it looks like this:

```
  uaClick2() {
    console.log("CLICKED UA 2")
    gtag('config', 'UA-146420424388-3', {
      'button_click': 'ua2'
    })
  }
```

When I click the button I see the gtag firing.  Where in the Google Analytics console can I look for these events.

I tried clicking on Report tabs (Realtime, Audience, Acquisition, etc.) but I don't see any reporting with the custom `button_click` event nor the number of times that the event has occurred.

Comment: I use a google plugin called Omnibug that tracks analytic events. Works great. After its installed it becomes a tab in the developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax to send an event is wrong.

To send Google Analytics Events on a web page where the global site tag has been added, you need to use the following syntax:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events